# cost function of Linear regression one variable on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to print with matplotlib a paraboloid, that is the cost function of a simple linear regression. The problem is that the function doesn't look a paraboloid...
[linear regression here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g7VE.png)
[fake paraboloid here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtQDp.png)
the perfect straight line is weight 2, bias 0

```
def main():
    #create database
    n_samples = 40
    x = np.linspace(0, 20, n_samples)
    y = 2*x + 4*np.random.randn(n_samples)

    #show
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    print_cost_func(x, y)

def cost_func(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, weight: int, bias: int) -> 
float:
    return np.sum((y - (weight*x + bias))**2) / (2*len(x))


def print_cost_func(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    weight = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.25)
    bias = np.arange(-50, 50, 0.25)
    weight, bias = np.meshgrid(weight, bias)

    Z = np.zeros((400, 400))
    #i think the problem is here
    for i in range(400):
        for j in range(400):
            Z[i][j] = cost_func(x, y, weight[i][j], bias[i][j])


    # Plot the surface.
    surf = ax.plot_surface(weight, bias, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    # Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.title('Cost function')
    plt.xlabel('Weight')
    plt.ylabel('Bias')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below on top of your code -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
```

[image]

Comment: I already import all those packages, it run, but if you see the image "fake paraboloid here" it isn't a paraboloid, it seems that the ndarray Z isn't correct

Comment: Added the result when I run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, you have a paraboloid.  It's just the gradient is very shallow along the bias axis.  I know because I am doing something very similar only from a stats approach, using SSE instead of loss, and I get the same plot.  Try reducing your weight range to (-20, 20) and you should see something more parabolic.[image: Regression paraboloid]